How do I get the warehouse size from the snowflake.account_usage tables/views?
The Snowflake ACCOUNT_USAGE schema has a lots of views, but I can't find a view that shows warehouse_name and warehouse_size over time.
I've checked SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.WAREHOUSE_EVENTS_HISTORY, SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.WAREHOUSE_LOAD_HISTORY and SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.WAREHOUSE_METERING_HISTORY but I don't think the warehouse size at a specific time can be inferred from there.
The SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.QUERY_HISTORY  contains the warehouse_name and warehouse_size but then you really need to scan the whole QUERY_HISTORY to get the warehouse_name to warehouse_size mapping and even the mapping is not perfect since you only have datapoints if there was actually a query for that warehouse.
Is there any better way to obtain the warehouse_size for a given warehouse_name at a given point in time?

I don't believe there is a view that gives you what you want. You could scan the query_history for CREATE/ALTER WAREHOUSE events and build the history from that. Just a suggestion - don't change warehouse sizes, just create a separate warehouses for each size you need, then you don't have issues trying to track the size of a warehouse at a specific point in time

warehouse_event_history gives you the exact query_id for any resize of a warehouse.  You could simply join that to query_history and get the exact statement that modified the warehouse and record the size.  It's less than ideal and worthy of a feature request.  In my opinion, warehouse_size should be part of warehouse_event_history and since that view is in Preview, getting feedback from customers would go a long way towards getting it implemented.

@MikeWalton , I'm up for giving feedback and even write a feature request, but what is the process exactly, you mean writing it in Snowflake Ideas?

I wrote "Track WAREHOUSE_SIZE changes in SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.WAREHOUSE_EVENTS_HISTORY" in snowflake ideas.

You can approximate with the following query that gives you the date, warehouse name and warehouse size
select date(start_time) as query_date, warehouse_name, mode(warehouse_size) as warehouse_size
from snowflake.account_usage.query_history
where warehouse_size is not null
group by query_date, warehouse_name
;

This query can be slow when performed on snowflake.account_usage views (takes 35 seconds for me)  so it's recommended to materialize the snowflake.account_usage.query_history into an actual database, In my case I materialize incrementally every day into account_usage.account_usage.query_history and performing the above query on it (676M rows) only takes 5 seconds (instead of 35 seconds).
